# Explain why unpack() returns different results in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

The following script finds prime numbers in a range from 1 to 13.
When I explicitly iterate over the table that contains the results I can see that the script works as expected. However, if I use `unpack()` function on the table only the first 3 numbers get printed out.

From docs: `unpack` is *"a special function with multiple returns. It receives an array and returns as results all elements from the array, starting from index 1"*.

Why is it not working in the script below?

```
t = {}
for i=1, 13 do t[i] = i end

primes = {}
for idx, n in ipairs(t) do
  local isprime = true
  for i=2, n-1 do
    if n%i == 0 then
      isprime = false
      break
    end
  end
  if isprime then
    primes[idx] = n
  end
end
print('loop printing:')
for i in pairs(primes) do
  print(i)
end
print('unpack:')
print(unpack(primes))
```

**Running**

```
$ lua5.3 primes.lua
loop printing:
1
2
3
5
7
13
11
unpack:
1   2   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
primes[idx] = n
```

to

```
primes[#primes+1] = n
```

The reason is that idx is not sequential as not every number is a prime.

Comment: The important (and missing) detail here is that [`unpack`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) operates on the "length of the list" and that the [length of a lua table](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) is undefined when it has "holes" in the array part.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for adding that.

Comment: @EtanReisner Good comment; Just nitpicking on "array part". The array part of a table is an implementation detail, and, in the standard implementation, it's possible the get a table into an internal state where the "array part" does not have holes yet the table does not have a "sequence."

Comment: @TomBlodget Fair point. Though in this instance I didn't mean the internal detail and just meant the integer key-space (as opposed to the non-integer key-space).

Comment: lua 5.3 manual links for [`table.unpack`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack) and the [length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7).

Comment: It's also important to note that `unpack` can be given an explicit range to unpack, so it isn't entirely reliant on the "array part" of the list..